Query that adds horizontal and vertical
I have data in a table that consists of expense statements by year. I want to make a SQL query that gives me the sum of the amounts but for a year on a line like in the Excel table that I provided. I tried but I can't do it. Only one line per year with all totals.


Re "but I can't do it" - show us first what you can do (ie query, which gives wrong results).

is total a field in the db or do you need to add transportation+meals+park as total in the query?

You can use the SQL GROUP BY clause to group your results by year and the SUM function to calculate the total expenses per category for each year.
SELECT Year,
       SUM(Transportation) AS Total_Transportation,
       SUM(Meals) AS Total_Meals,
       SUM(Park) AS Total_Park,
       SUM(Total) AS Grand_Total
FROM ExpensesTable
GROUP BY Year;

SQL fiddle code
click here to see what you want.

I suppose OP's table has no total column. (I.e. it's a calculated value.)

It works thanks
